# Replace specific entries of a multidimensional arrays avoiding loops

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I would like to replace the entry corresponding to the column number of an array that is part of a 3D matrix by zero. My matrix is of size `IxJxJ`. In each column `j` I can find a matrix of size `IxJ`of which I would like to replace the `j`th column by zero.

You can find below an example of what I would like using a simple 3D matrix `A`. This example uses a loop, which is what I am trying to avoid.

```
A(:,:,1) = randi([1,2],5,3);
A(:,:,2) = randi([3,4],5,3);
A(:,:,3) = randi([5,6],5,3);

for i = 1:3
    B = A(:,i,:);
    B = squeeze(B);
    B(:,i) = 0;
    A(:,i,:) = B;
end
```

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid loops? Is it because you heard that loops are slow in MATLAB? Cos that hasn’t been true in 15 years or so.

Comment: Well yes, I guess that is the reason. It is part of a minimization procedure —obviously using much bigger matrices than A—, and so far replacing loops has reduced computational time tremendously, but that may not be true for all kinds of operations. Intuitively a loop seems inefficient for this operation, but my intuition could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can replace the 4 lines of code in your for loop with just `A(:,i,i) = 0;`. I don't see any real need to avoid the `for` loop.

Using linear indexing, you can do

```
A((1:size(A,1)).'+size(A,1).*(size(A,2)+1).*(0:size(A,2)-1)) = 0
```

or for older version of Matlab without implicit expansion (pre-R2016b)

```
A(bsxfun(@plus,(1:size(A,1)).',size(A,1).*(size(A,2)+1).*(0:size(A,2)-1))) = 0
```

After some very quick testing, it actually looks like the `bsxfun` solution is fastest, but the differences aren't huge, your results may differ.

Comment: It is part of a minimization so even small differences matter. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use [eye](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eye.html) to create a logical mask and mutiply it by A.

```
  A = A .* reshape(~eye(3), 1, 3, 3) ;
```